# Edit trying to make a library in js with OOP

Tags: javascript, java

**Edit - more specific and what I tried based on the comments and it did not achieve my goal**

So I am trying to make a Gui library for ModPE scripters. Instead of them typing it all I want it to be predefined and organized in classes. So I do all the thinking and solving and they can create GUI mods more easier. I fixed and tried...

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();
function newLevel()
{
    ctx.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        run: function()
        {
            try
            {
                var PopupsAndLayouts = {
                    PopupWindow: new android.widget.PopupWindow(ctx),
                    LinearLayout: new android.widget.LinearLayout(ctx),
                                Button: new android.widget.Button(ctx);
                    wrapContect: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    fillParent: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                    leftTopCorner: [ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), android.view.Gravity.TOP | android.view.Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0]
                };
                var myWindow = PopupsAndLayouts.PopupWindow;
                var myLayout = PopupsAndLayouts.LinearLayout;
                var myButton = PopupsAndLayouts.Button;
                myLayout.addView(myButton);
                myWindow.setContentView(myLayout);
                myWindow.setHeight(wrapContent);
                myWindow.setWidth(wrapContent);
                myWindow.showAtLocation(leftTopCorner);
                //Then they add more widgets or set their script
            }
            catch (libError)
            {
                print(error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it wont work. The point is organized classes so instead of them have to know 
    var myButton = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
    OR 
    var myLayout = new android.widget.LinearLayout(ctx);

They just type 
    var myLayout = Layouts.LinearLayout;
    OR
    var myButton = Widgets.Buttons.Button;

How do I do that exactly? I am lost and want to build this library any thoughts?

What about GridLayout? Not OOP wise though just in general.

Comment: `var PopupsAndLayouts = { var` is all wrong...

Comment: As I said before I dont do classes and objects too much in Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GridLayout you can do it this way

```
var ctx = com.mojang.minecraftpe.MainActivity.currentMainActivity.get();
function newLevel()
{
    ctx.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
        run: function()
        {
            try
            {
                var l = new android.widget.GridLayout(ctx);
                var b1 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
                var b2 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
                var b3 = new android.widget.Button(ctx);
                var ba = [b1, b2, b3];
                for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++)
                {
                    bl.addView(ba[i]);
                }
                var p = new android.widget.PopupWindow(l, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.showAtLocation(ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), android.view.Gravity.CENTER | android.view.Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (defaultError)
            {
                print(defaultError);
        }
    });
}
```

The for loop provides flexibility but if you prefer not to then what you can do it just add them like....

```
l.addView(b1, b2, b3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This look's more like javascript ... but I don't know OOP, so I can't say I have the right answer.

```
var PopupsAndLayouts = {
   PopupWindow: new android.widget.PopupWindow(ctx),
   LinearLayout: new android.widget.LinearLayout(ctx),
   Button: new android.widget.Button(ctx),
   wrapContent: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   fillParent: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
   leftTopCorner: [ctx.getWindow().getDecorView(), android.view.Gravity.TOP | android.view.Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0]
};
```

Comment: Ah okay... So I did the class wrong. And yes it is Java (Rhino) Java in javascript rhino